# How to apply theme to PyGTK Application

Tags: python, gtk, themes, pygtk

**Is it possible to apply this [GTK+ theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Elegant+Brit?content=74553&PHPSESSID=1ec9ce6534c48632d0ebc64a2a3ee830) in my PyGTK application?**

Can I apply the theme programatically? Ie, to apply the theme do I use a PyGTK function or do I have to find where PyGTK is installed on my machine(Inside Python2.7) and change the arrow .pngs, and the scrollbar .pngs and etc.?

Note I only have PyGTK installed I dont have GTK+ installed, do I need that? Will the theme linked above work for PyGTK or only for GTK+?

**Can you provide advice on how I can apply this theme to my PyGTK application?**

Comment: If you have PyGTK then you also have GTK+ (which is the underlying library).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you download the first package from your link, the one that's labelled "(GTK & Metacity themes)" you should get a tar.gz archive. Unpack the archive into some folder like `/home/jake/.themes`. 
Then in your pygtk code, before you initialize your widgets(I would do it right after you import pygtk and gtk in your code), add this line:

`gtk.rc_parse('/home/jake/.themes/Elegant Brit/gtk-2.0/gtkrc')`

That `gtkrc` file in that directory contains the information used to tell gtk how to draw the widgets for that theme.

Hope that helps.

Note: Theme choices should be left up to the user and it is generally frowned upon to change/modify the current user's theme when developing an application using gtk.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph and for being decent enough to write the paragraphs preceding it - I would have left them off ;-)

Comment: IMO your note about not changing theme only applies for Linux - especially Gnome - users, no problem at all if you developing for Windows.

Comment: @ms4py I generally agree with you, as gtk on windows is generally used  for a very select number of applications and not an entire environment. But, nevertheless, it's how gtk was designed and the philosophy to keep in mind when developing gtk applications